# Showing a certain random process is a Markov Process

Tags: probability, markov-process

I have the following example of a random process: A person has two houses, house A and house B in which he can stay, we denote by $X_{i}\in\left\{ A,B\right\}$
  the house he stayed in on the i-th day and it is given that:$$P\left(X_{i}=B\,|\, X_{i-1}=A\right)=q$$
$$P\left(X_{i}=A\,|\, X_{i-1}=A\right)=1-q$$
$$P\left(X_{i}=B\,|\, X_{i-1}=B\right)=1-p$$
$$P\left(X_{i}=A\,|X_{i-1}=B\right)=p$$
 I need to show that this random process is a Markov-Process and find a stationary distribution for it. I know the definitions of a Markov-Process and a stationary distribution but I've never seen an example of how to show/find them so I'm pretty much completely lost.

Comment: What is your definition of a Markov process? Because this seems to be almost by definition a Markov process.  I guess you could go to the formal steps of show that $p+(1-p)=1$ and $q+(1-q)=1$.

Comment: You're right really... 
I'm not sure really what their point was with this question, it was more confusing than anything. It's always fun to take a course where the exercises aren't actually related to what they did in class. Thanks regardless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove given process is markov , show that $P(X_i=x_i|X_{i-1}=x_{i-1},X_{i-2}=x_{i-2},\cdots,X_0=x_0)=P(X_i=x_i|X_{i-1}=x_{i-1})$

To show that start with $i=2$ and use induction.

EDIT: Transition probability matrix $P$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1-q \ \ \ \  q \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ p \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1-p\end{pmatrix}$

Let stationary probabilities be $\pi =(p_1,p_2)$, then solve for $\pi $ using  $\pi P=\pi$

Comment: And regarding finding a stationary distribution?